# Ajax call not working, when trying to check if username already exists in the database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have written the php code for signup form. Its working without Ajax call. But when I used Ajax call for checking duplicate username, it does not get called.

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" class="LoginForm">
    First Name: <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required name="s_f_n" class="user_input" />
    Last Name: <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required name="s_l_n" class="user_input" />
    Email:<input type="email" placeholder="Email" required name="s_u_id" class="user_input" />
    Username: <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required name="s_u_n" class="user_input" />
    Password:<input type="password" placeholder="Password" required name="s_u_p" class="user_input" />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" formvalidate name="signup" class="inSub" id="su"/>
</form>
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $('#su').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                     type: 'post',
                     url: 'ajax.php',
                     data: {'ajax': true},
                    success: function(){
                        window.alert("success");
                    }
                });
            });
});
```

ajax.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && ($_POST['ajax']) == true){
            $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
            if(!$conn){
                die(mysql_error());
            } else {
                mysql_select_db('users');
                $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['s_f_n']);
                $lname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['s_l_n']);
                $em = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['s_u_id']);
                $uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['s_u_n']);
                $p = md5($_POST['s_u_p']);

                $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `udata` WHERE username_user = '$uname'";
                $result = mysql_query($sql_query);
                if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                    //trying to see if this part works
                    header("Location: https://www.google.com");
                    mysql_close();
                } else {
                    $sql_query = "INSERT INTO `users`.`udata` (firstname, lastname, email_id, username_user, pd) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$em', '$uname', '$p')";

                    $sub_query_ret_val = mysql_query($sql_query, $conn);
                    if(!$sub_query_ret_val){
                        die(mysql_error());
                    }

                    mysql_close();
                }

            }
    }
```

**Ajax.php neither checks for the duplicate, nor enters the data into mysql database**

**ANSWER by: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com**

```
data:$(".LoginForm").serialize()
```

worked perfectly.

Comment: You need to see what is happening with the request, best way to do this is to hit `F-12` in your browser to bring up the debug console and look at the request and response.

Comment: Put ***var_dump($_POST);*** at the top of ajax.php and post the result.

Comment: Are you sure you get uname value proper thru form here `$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['s_u_n']);` ?

Comment: @DavidCorbin it does not display any post data: "array(0) { } "

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com yes, i'm sure about it. When I tried it without ajax call it worked like charm, but unfortunately now it does not work.

Comment: Why dont you send like `data:{'sentData':form.serialize()}` ?

Comment: Post your Full HTML for Form

Comment: You didnt mention in Question that `"It does not work thru ajax but works for only PHP form submit(reload page)"`

Comment: Put ***console.log("clicked");*** after ***$('#su').click(function(){*** to make sure the send function is being called.

Comment: Probably your form must be submitted and the page re-loads each time you click the "Sign Up" button, right? Add a preventDefault to your js code.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com my bad. I have edited the quetion with full html form

Comment: @DavidCorbin It works fine and displays "Clicked" in the console.

Comment: `Class="` is not having END Quotes.   **`:(`**

Comment: @ash_8247 Tried that one, with no luck.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com so sorry, that was a typo. I don't know why i'm making silly mistakes.

Comment: You can use the developer tools in your browser( check the network tab in developer tools) to see the page load and ajax calls etc... Check how its working now.

Comment: @AhmedDhanani Can you please check it and let us know what's happening?

Comment: @ash_8247 actually I don't know how to use the dev tool in firefox.

Comment: Hit F12 on your keyboard, it will launch the developer tools in your browser. In the developer tools you can see many tabs. Click on the Network tab (aka. net). Then run your code and check the content. 

Developer tools are very helpful in debugging js codes. Try firebug on FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use input button

```
<input type="button" value="Sign Up" formvalidate name="signup" class="inSub" id="su"/>
```

Now form wont reload the page which used to reload in your code.

**Edit:**

`$("form").serialize();` is used to form Key : Value pair of Inputs automatically. So if your form has 100 fields , instead of doing horrible `data:{'field1':$("#field1Input").val(),..........'field1':$("#field100Input").val()}` . `serialize()` method serializes form data in `key:value,key2:value2` pair.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it actually does not runs that function on the ajax.php. Neither enters the new one into database nor checks for the existing one. Its the same scenario with both type "submit" and type="button"

Comment: use `data: {'ajax': true,'s_f_n':$("[name='s_f_n']") },` like this  as you need to pass what fields ajax needs to send to PHP, use all fields you need to pass to php thru ajax. Or use `data:$("form").serialize()`

Comment: No chages. Does Ajax calls depends on browser?

Comment: post your Code you modified as i told.

Comment: here it is:
`$('#su').click(function(){
                    
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'ajax.php',
                        data: {'ajax': true,'s_f_n':$("[name='s_f_n']") },
                        success: function(){
                            window.alert("success");
                        }
                    });`

ajax.php:

`if(isset($_POST['ajax'])){
    //rest of the code
}`

Comment: Hi buddy I told you to use same syntax for other fields as well like s_l_n like this in ajax. No worry LEAVE IT . Use `data:$("form").serialize()` instead of modified code **`:(`**

Comment: What about the ajax.php? I mean what does this `$form.serialize()` sends? does this line remains the same? `if(isset($_POST['ajax'])){ //rest of the code }`

Comment: @AhmedDhanani , Just first use `data:$(".LoginForm").serialize()` . If You say it works then I will let you know what it does. Getting ??? Please do it bro **`:(`**

Comment: Thanks buddy, thanks a million it worked perfectly :) But I still don't get waht this `$("form").serialize()` does?

Comment: Ok :) Now I am happy to tell you. Let me edit the question. You can accept the answer too. Its tick mark at the right side of answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without preventDefault() your page can be reloaded each time you click on the submit button. Try including the preventDefault() as shown below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#su').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url: 'ajax.php',
             data: {'ajax': true},
            success: function(){
                window.alert("success");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @ahmed I have tested and found it working. If you've tried this, please let me know the result.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. But I the error was in sending the data. Your guide for the dev tools helped me. Thanks alot.